# Gridview to Excel in Asp.net C#, the excel file is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, xlsx

I am trying to Export my gridview data to excel file and its being downloaded but empty cell,
i am using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;" and when the export button being clicked the following code will run :

```
            // Create a new Excel Application
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            // Create a new workbook and set it as the active workbook
            var workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            var worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

            // Set the column headers from the GridView
            for (int i = 0; i < DisplayWPR.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = DisplayWPR.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }

            // Set the data rows from the GridView
            for (int i = 0; i < DisplayWPR.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < DisplayWPR.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = DisplayWPR.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text;
                }
            }

            // Save the workbook
            string fileName = "WPR_Report_Exel.xlsx";
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files") + fileName;
            workbook.SaveAs(filePath);

            // Close the workbook and Excel application
            workbook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();

            // Download the Excel file
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
            Response.End();
```

need help plz.

Comment: Does the code error out? Is the Excel sheet saved before you export? And last but not least, does the file download? We kind of need at what point this fails, else we much playing a guessing game here. From what you suggest, the Excel sheet does download, but does not have any data?